# How to fix my crawler in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler

```
Regex hrefs = new Regex("<a href.*?>");
Regex http = new Regex("http:.*?>");  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string source = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
foreach (Match m in hrefs.Matches(source)){
sb.Append(http.Match(m.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(http.Match(m.ToString()));
}
```

The codes works fine, but just once problem 
Look at the output.

```
http://images.google.se/imghp?hl=sv&tab=wi" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb1>
http://video.google.se/?hl=sv&tab=wv" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb1>
http://maps.google.se/maps?hl=sv&tab=wl" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb1>
http://news.google.se/nwshp?hl=sv&tab=wn" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb1>
http://translate.google.se/?hl=sv&tab=wT" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb1>
http://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=sv&tab=wm" class=gb1>
http://www.google.se/intl/sv/options/" onclick="this.blur();gbar.tg(event);return !1" aria-haspopup=true class=gb3>
http://blogsearch.google.se/?hl=sv&tab=wb" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb2>
http://www.youtube.com/?hl=sv&tab=w1&gl=SE" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb2>
http://www.google.com/calendar/render?hl=sv&tab=wc" class=gb2>
http://picasaweb.google.se/home?hl=sv&tab=wq" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb2>
http://docs.google.com/?hl=sv&tab=wo" class=gb2>
http://www.google.se/reader/view/?hl=sv&tab=wy" class=gb2>
http://sites.google.com/?hl=sv&tab=w3" class=gb2>
http://groups.google.se/grphp?hl=sv&tab=wg" onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gb2>
http://www.google.se/ig%3Fhl%3Dsv%26source%3Diglk&usg=AFQjCNEsLWK4azJkUc3KrW46JTUSjK4vhA" class=gb4>
http://www.google.se/" class=gb4>
http://www.google.com/intl/sv/landing/games10/index.html">
http://www.google.com/ncr">
```

How can i remove the html tags?

Answer (score 11):

Change your regex to:

```
Regex http = new Regex("http:.*?\"");
```

Or even better, parse all links using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and Xpath:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"); // Will find all links

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a non-regex solution. Parsing real-world HTML can be tricky and I consider regex a 90% solution. If I need something more bulletproof than that I use a tool designed for the task at hand.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is bad. Unless you need the performance, go for something that can do the job properly

Answer (score 2):

The quick solution is to change this:

```
Regex http = new Regex("http:.*?>");
```

To this:

```
Regex http = new Regex("http:.*?\"");
```

The better solution is to use a library to parse the html - the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) can be used for that and will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Substring the following line http.Match(m.ToString()) to http.Match(m.ToString().remove(m.ToString().IndexOf("\"")))

Not the cleanest way to do it but it works

Answer (score 0):

Change the closing tag to be `"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex hrefs = new Regex("<a href.*?>");
Regex http = new Regex("(http:.*?)\"");  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string source = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
foreach (Match m in hrefs.Matches(source))
{
    var value = http.Match(m.ToString()).Groups[1].Value;
    sb.Append(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice and simple solution. Match any character after http: except " character

```
"http:[^\"]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

FilesAndImages: `<\s*(?<Tag>(applet|embed|frame|img|link|script|xml))\s*.*?(?<AttributeName>(src|href|xhref))\s*=\s*[\"\'](?<FileOrImage>.*?)[\"\']`

HyperLinks: `<\s*(?<Tag>(a|form|frame))\s*.*?(?<AttributeName>(action|href|src))\s*=\s*[\"\'](?<HyperLink>.*?)[\"\']`

Comment: The `*` character makes things italic, and the `<` character is interpreted as HTML. Use ` to protect your text. [Formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).